# How many users can access Apex sales force at same time in same Org?

Tags: salesforce, apex

Did anybody know how many users can access Apex developer console at the same time for one Org?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all a good idea to share access to the Developer Console in a single org. While it's possible (I don't think there is a strict limit, although I may be wrong), it's risky because there is a high chance that developer changes will conflict and overwrite one another.

Further, the Developer Console is not very user-friendly in a shared org; developers may experience confusion around test result reporting, for example.

Provision one environment per developer, preferably a scratch org, but a Developer or Developer Pro sandbox if scratch orgs are not available.

You should also seriously consider moving to Visual Studio Code with the Salesforce extension pack and using version control. Developer Console does not work with modern development practices, and by using it in this way you are accumulating technical debt.